# What are the formulae used in R by predict.lm when interval= a) 'none', b) 'prediction', and c) 'confidence'?

Tags: r, regression, linear

The references provided in the R documentation for predict.lm, taken together, actually leave open a number of possibilities for the formulae for confidence and prediction intervals (including the possible use of tolerance intervals as prediction intervals, though they are not the same thing). My unfamiliarity with the innards of R prevents me from extracting the formulae from the code for predict. Can anyone please provide the formulae actually used?

Comment: +1 for trying to read the source code before asking. Although I think you ought to know how the `none` case works...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prediction `"none"` is clearly no prediction. To understand the other options, the relevant part of `predict.lm` is this:

```
tfrac <- qt((1 - level)/2, df)
hwid <- tfrac * switch(interval, confidence = sqrt(ip), 
    prediction = sqrt(ip + pred.var))
```

Where `ip` is the square of the fitted standard error and `pred.var` is the variance of the residuals (under the default options).

Consider the following example:

```
mdl <- lm(hp~disp,mtcars)
predict(mdl,newdata=list(disp=300),se.fit=TRUE,interval="confidence")
$fit
       fit      lwr      upr
1 177.0003 159.2944 194.7062

$se.fit
[1] 8.669712

$df
[1] 30

$residual.scale
[1] 42.6459
```

One can recreate the confidence interval (approximately due to rounding of parameters for brevity) with:

```
177.003 + qt(0.025,30)*c(1,-1)*8.669712
[1] 159.2971 194.7089
```

Similarly the prediction interval can be computed with:

```
177.003 + qt(0.025,30)*c(1,-1)*sqrt(8.669712^2+var(mdl$residuals))
[1]  89.51433 264.49167

predict(mdl,newdata=list(disp=300),interval="prediction")
       fit      lwr      upr
1 177.0003 88.12423 265.8764
```

Comment: Thanks, though I'm disappointed (especially for the confidence intervals) that these are single-point intervals. Draper & Smith and Miller use F instead of t to provide a confidence band for the whole line. Is there an R package with a function that does that?

Comment: Yes, at least for confidence intervals: investr

Comment: The (slight) discrepancy between your prediction interval and the one computed by `predict.lm` arises as you're computing the prediction variance as `var(mdl$residuals)`. If you use `sum(mdl$residuals ^ 2) / mdl$df.residual)` instead, you should get the exact same answer as R.

Answer (score 0):

I can show you some steps how the predict() function calculates for 3 different intervals. I will be taking **mtcars** as an example and predicting intervals (none, confidence and prediction) at wt = 3 (3000lb)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(UsingR)
data(mtcars)
y<-mtcars$mpg
x<-mtcars$wt

fit<-lm(y~x)
none<-predict(fit,newdata = data.frame(x=3),interval = "none")
con<-predict(fit,newdata = data.frame(x=3),interval = "confidence")
pred<-predict(fit,newdata = data.frame(x=3),interval = "prediction")

g<-ggplot(data=mtcars,aes(x=wt,y=mpg))
g<-g+geom_point(size=2, color = "black", alpha = 0.4)
g<-g+geom_smooth(method = "lm")
g<-g+ggtitle("Prediction vs Confidence using predict()")+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
g<-g+labs(x ="wt", y = "mpg")
g<-g+geom_point(aes(x=3,y=pred[3]),colour = "red") #95% prediction level
g<-g+geom_point(aes(x=3,y=con[3]),colour = "blue") #95% confidence level
g

#From the predict() function
none
con 
pred

ssx<-round(sum((x-mean(x))^2),2)

#From the manual calculations using formula
con[1] + c(-1,1) * qt(.975,df = fit$df) * sigma(fit) * sqrt(1/n + (3-    mean(x))^2/ssx) #confidence interval
pred[1] + c(-1,1) * qt(.975,df = fit$df) * sigma(fit) * sqrt(1 + 1/n + (3-mean(x))^2/ssx) #prediction interval
```

[image]

In calculations, which are the last 2 steps in  the code above, the only difference is in the standard error calculations (*for **none** we dont output any intervals so understood*). The small variations which I am getting may be the case due to rounding issues.
So the formula used are pretty much from the theory which are:

**standard error used for Confidence interval**:

[image]

**standard error used for Prediction interval**:

[image]